# Return number of results from Doctrine query that uses createQuery

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

```
$q = $this->_em->createQuery("SELECT s FROM app\models\Quest s 
                                    LEFT JOIN s.que c
                                    WHERE s.type = '$sub'
                                    AND c.id = '$id'");
```

Given a query like the one above, how would I retrieve the number of results?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively one can look at what Doctrine Paginator class does to a Query object to get a count (this aproach is most probably an overkill though, but it answers your question):

```
public function count()
{
if ($this->count === null) {
    /* @var $countQuery Query */
    $countQuery = $this->cloneQuery($this->query);

    if ( ! $countQuery->getHint(CountWalker::HINT_DISTINCT)) {
        $countQuery->setHint(CountWalker::HINT_DISTINCT, true);
    }

    if ($this->useOutputWalker($countQuery)) {
        $platform = $countQuery->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform(); // law of demeter win

        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        $rsm->addScalarResult($platform->getSQLResultCasing('dctrn_count'), 'count');

        $countQuery->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\CountOutputWalker');
        $countQuery->setResultSetMapping($rsm);
    } else {
        $countQuery->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_TREE_WALKERS, array('Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\CountWalker'));
    }

    $countQuery->setFirstResult(null)->setMaxResults(null);

    try {
        $data =  $countQuery->getScalarResult();
        $data = array_map('current', $data);
        $this->count = array_sum($data);
    } catch(NoResultException $e) {
        $this->count = 0;
    }
}
return $this->count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either perform a count query beforehand:

```
$count = $em->createQuery('SELECT count(s) FROM app\models\Quest s 
                                    LEFT JOIN s.que c
                                    WHERE s.type=:type
                                    AND c.id=:id)
                 ->setParameter('type', $sub);
                 ->setParameter('id', $id);
                 ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Or you can just execute your query and get the size of the results array:

```
$quests = $q->getResult();
$count = count($quests);
```

Use the first method if you need the count so that you can make a decision before actually retrieving the objects.